# Question about calling async function inside another function

Tags: javascript

For example for my api call I got this function

```js
async function signUp(params) {
 await api..call
}
```

then In my component I call this form submit function

```js
const submit = async (info) => {
 
 }
```

should I still call it as await.signUp(info) inside the submit function or await is not needed here because the original function is async / await? How should this look properly? Maybe async await is not needed anymore if the signUp function is async?

Comment: An `async function` always returns a promise, which you need to handle somehow - with `await`, with `.then()`, or by ignoring it. It doesn't magically become synchronous from the outside if that's what you mean.

Comment: I am asking do I need to do signUp(); or await signUp() inside submit function or does submit even needs to be `async` if signUp already is

Comment: Yes and yes. If you don't `await` it, you cannot get it's result. If you don't mark `submit` as `async`, you cannot use `await`

Comment: If I dont mark submit as sync, then I call signUp then it will still be await because signUp has await function inside it? Like it wont go to next line of code until signUp completes

Comment: No, it won't, it will return a promise immediately. Just try it!

Answer (score 2):

You may or may not require it depending on the use case.

---

Here is an example to illustrate further the usage of multiple async/await

**With await**:

The `child` blocks the `parent` from completing its execution. Therefore `parent` ends only once the `child` ends.

```js
const delay = (time) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res(), time));

const parent1 = async() => {
  console.log("parent started");
  await child();
  console.log("parent ended");
}

const child = async() => {
  console.log("child started");
  await delay(1000);
  console.log("child ended");
} 

// Results with await 
parent1();

console.log("-----------------------");
```

**Without await**:

The `child` *does not* block the `parent` from completing its execution. Therefore `parent` finishes before the `child` finishes.

```js
const delay = (time) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res(), time));

const parent2 = async() => {
  console.log("parent started");
  child();
  console.log("parent ended");
}

const child = async() => {
  console.log("child started");
  await delay(1000);
  console.log("child ended");
} 

// Results with w/o await
parent2();

console.log("-----------------------");
```

Comment: Is there any valid documentation for this use case?